# How to prevent -> from being formatted into an inverted question mark

Tags: formatting, punctuation

I am trying to write a document where I have multipled instances of `-->`, `<--`, `---->` etc... as it's a formatted answer to a referee response (and it follows their styling). However, LaTeX seems to convert all instances of `->` into inverted question marks, and all instances of `<-` into upside down exclamation points.

Is there a way to block this from happening? Preferably some sort of command at the beginning of the document that would apply throughout and reroute whatever escape character this is triggering, or otherwise some way to escape this?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Thanks that was quick. I'm still sort of new to LaTeX, what does this solution do specifically? It seems to have worked